# How to clear tk2text box in R tcltk2, tcltk

Tags: r, tcltk, tcltk2

I am trying to clear the content of a text box which i created using

```
Window_1$env$txt1 <- tk2text(Window_1, width = 90, height = 1)
```

I can update the values using

```
tkinsert(Window_1$env$txt1 "end", "test")
```

But can someone help me how to clear the contents of Window_1$env$txt1

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :) 
to delete the text box I have to use tkdelete

```
tktag.add(Window_1$env$txt1, "sel", "0.0", "end") #tagging the selecting
tkdelete(Window_1$env$txt1, "sel.first", "sel.last")
tkinsert(Window_1$env$txt1, "end", "new_text")
```